# Disable "divert attention" warning in MB?

Tags: mercedes-benz

I have a 2013 Mercedes S550 and whenever it starts the screen has a big warning that says "Caution: Using COMAND may not divert your attention away from road and traffic" or something like that. The problem is that it prevents the back up camera from being used because the warning appears on the same screen.

Is there any easy way to disable this warning?

Answer (score 0):

Carly may be the product you're looking for (https://www.mycarly.com/en/app/). Check their website carefully for compatibility, but their adapter + app may be able to help you configure your car. 
Their stuff seems to mostly work, I've tried it on a BMW X5, however the customer service is sub par.